# Need assistance with MongoDB, Python, HTML, and Ajax

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask, datatables

I am stumped I have searched and I cannot seem to find what I am looking for. My client wants to view the MongoDB data in an HTML table preferably using DataTables and Ajax.

The issue is the method I found saves all the data to the HTML causing it to take a long time to load.

The other way was to store the data on their digital server as a .json but once the .json reaches over 1,000 kb their server starts to lag.

So my question is if there is another way to view the data in HTML without appending it directly in the HTML or exporting it to their server as a .json?

They are using Python 2.7 and Ubuntu 20.04.2 for their digital server.

Comment: Assuming you are using pagination with data tables, you might want to consider lazy loading, and use a database cursor.  Fetch only the records you need for the initial page, but keep the cursor open.  When a user navigates to the next page they fetch the next set from the database, and thus the load latency is distributed among each page request.

Comment: To follow up on the lazy loading approach: DataTables (and the browser in which it is rendered) will potentially suffer from poor performance if you try to send all the data to DataTables up-front (assuming thousands/millions of records). The most typical solution (if you stick with DataTables) is to use [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side). The upside is: this should perform well, as you only send 1 page of results at a time to the browser.  The downside is: the server needs to implement all paging, sorting and filtering logic.

Comment: DataTables works fine when the HTML is using a .json file. But when each row of the table is saved in the HTML it takes a very long time to load. So I would like to use a .json but it cannot be stored on the server because that causes the server to lag. I thought MongoDB could be the solution but I cannot seem to figure out how to display the data from MongoDB without saving it to the server as a .json or appending it in HTML.

Comment: "_a very long time to load_" - Agreed - that sounds like an argument in favor of server-side processing. "_it (json) cannot be stored on the server_" - JSON does not need to be stored on the server - maybe you can clarify what you mean?

Comment: When the JSON was saved on the server the server experienced lag meaning the program that the server was running had lag because the file size of the JSON was high. I did a few tests and found that once the JSON reached an amount past 1,000 KB the lag started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this. I would appreciate any revisions to make it better. I am still a beginner at coding and this is what I learned through research so I apologize in advance if it is missing any key components.

Flask App named "record.py"

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, abort, jsonify, Response
import pymongo
import logging
import json
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson import json_util
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        return super(MyEncoder, self).default(obj)

# client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<Username>:<password>@<cluster_name_all_lowercase>.wncwk.mongodb.net/<Cluster_Name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<Username>:<password>@<cluster_name_all_lowercase>.wncwk.mongodb.net/<Cluster_Name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
mydb = client["bs"] # Database name
msgs = mydb["ChatEST"] # Collection name

app = Flask(__name__)
app.json_encoder = MyEncoder

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('chatmsg.html')

@app.route('/ChatEST')
def Msgs():
    ChatEST = list(msgs.find({}))
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId
    return json.dumps(ChatEST, default = json_util.default)
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run("0.0.0.0", 4884, debug = True)
```

HTML template named "chatmsg.html"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-3.5.1.min.js') }}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
 <head lang="en">
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='thegr8.css') }}"/> /* Custome CSS file */
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap.min.css') }}"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery.dataTables.min.css') }}"/>
     <title>Title</title>
     <style>
     {padding-top: 1.25%; padding-right: 0.25%; padding-bottom: 1.25%; padding-left: 0.25%;}
     </style>
 </head>
 <center></span><div class="table-responsive"></div></span></center>
     <table id="chatTable" class="display" width="100%" style="height:auto;width:100%;min-width:1%;font-size:2vw;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.25)">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Name</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Message</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Date</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Account ID</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Global ID</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tfoot>
             <tr>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Name</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Message</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Date</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Account ID</th>
                 <th class="sorttable_alpha" width=auto>Global ID</th>
             </tr>
         </tfoot>
     </table>
 <script>
 function setupData() {
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var table = $('#chatTable').DataTable({
             initComplete: function () {
                 api = this.api();
                 this.api().columns().every( function () {
                     api.order.listener($(this.footer()), this.index(), null);
                    });
                },
             "ajax": {
                 // "url": "static/objects2.txt", // This works for the static file.
                 "url": "/ChatEST", // This now works too thanks to @kthorngren
                 "dataType": "json",
                 "dataSrc": ""},
                 "columns": [
                     { "data": "name", "name": "name"},
                     { "data": "msg", "name": "msg" },
                     { "data": "msgTime", "name": "msgTime", "defaultContent": "" },
                     { "data": "player", "name": "player" },
                     { "data": "accountID", "name": "accountID",
                        fnCreatedCell: function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            if(oData.player) {
                                $(nTd).html("<a href=http://Creating_a_link_with_a_piece_of_the_data.com"+oData.accountID+" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>"+ "GID" +"</a>");
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ],
                lengthMenu: [ [3, 5, 8, 33, 55, 88, 1000], [3, 5, 8, 33, 55, 88, 1000] ], // Need help making this dynamic so as the .json data increases the Length Menu number also increases.
                pageLength: 3,
                paging: true,
                deferRender: true,
                responsive: true,
                scrollY: 300,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                scroller: {rowHeight: 10}
            });
        });
    }
 $( window ).on( "load", setupData );
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```